# Android Facebook Access Token Is Null

Tags: android, facebook

I can connect through my app (I can see on my profile preferences online that the permissions were granted to the app). I log through the app but when I want to get my access token, it is returned as null...

This is my onCreate method of my application:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    getFbKeyHash();
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext(), new FacebookSdk.InitializeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onInitialized() {
            if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null){
                System.out.println("not logged in yet");
                isFBLogged = false;
            } else {
                isFBLogged = true;
                System.out.println("Logged in");
            }
        }
    });
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
}
```

In my activity, I use this method:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(FacebookTest.this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```

This is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <provider
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true"/>

    <activity android:name=".Activity.FacebookTest">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity.MainActivity" />
</application>
```

Any clue why I don't have any access token?

Comment: did you try to use LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);

Comment: What am I supposed to do with this...?

Comment: you can receive the result from logging in and get the accesstoken

Comment: Can you be more precise on how to accomplish this? :)

Comment: do you want to use login button?

Comment: If I can do without it, I'd prefer that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email",
                    "user_birthday"));



        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
    }

    FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
           // success
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // cancel
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            // error
        }
    };



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```